# Is ACAccount identifier unique for all devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, acaccount

Is property identifier ACAccount unique for all devices?

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011019-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4) can't tell anything, just "unique identifier". On one device or on all devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The identifier propertt is unique per account on device only. It is not unique across devices. I have yet to find any actual documentation around this, but have extensively tested across devices and the simulator. Hope this helps.